# Belongs_to relationship not behaving as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

I have the following two objects:

```
class Layout < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :content_panels, foreign_key: :layout_uuid, primary_key: :uuid
  . . .
end
```

and

```
class ContentPanel < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :layout, foreign_key: :layout_uuid, primary_key: :uuid
    . . .
end
```

If I do the following:

```
layout = Layout.create
=> #<Layout id: 42, uuid: nil>
```

I expect the following to work

```
content_panel = layout.content_panels.create
=> #<ContentPanel id: 31, layout_id: nil, layout_uuid: nil, uuid: nil>
```

. . .  and it does, except when I call:

```
content_panel.layout 
=> nil
```

I get `nil`, always.  *I should be getting the `layout` object I created it with?*

But if I call:

```
layout.content_panels
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ContentPanel id: 31, layout_id: nil, layout_uuid: nil, uuid: nil>]>
```

I get a list of objects that contains the `content_panel` I created above.

What makes my `content_panel.layout` value always equal nil and not the object it belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

Your `layout = Layout.create` call is not creating the `uuid` which you're using as your primary key to associate your two models.  So without a `uuid` set then there's no way for Rails to set the `layout_uuid` in the `ContentPanel` and hence no way for it to record the association in the DB.